# How to set a global pool for azure pipeline jobs?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an azure pipeline like following:

```
target:
- main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
      name: APool
    steps
      -script: ....
  - job: B1
    pool: 
      name: APool
    steps
      -script: ....
```

APool is defined in agents.

I set same pool in jobs seperately. But I want to define a global pool top of pipeline.yaml file and use it in stages.

How can I do this?

Comment: By defining it at the pipeline level? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines Although not really sure what you are trying to do since the description is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use variables.

```
variables:
- name: mypool
  value: 'APool'

target:
- main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
      name: ${{ variables.mypool }}
    steps
      -script: ....
  - job: B1
    pool: 
      name: ${{ variables.mypool }}
    steps
      -script: ....
```

Comment: I mean not a variable, define a pool object that includes demands.